# retrieve index of drop element

Tags: jquery, ipad, drag-and-drop

I am using webkit drag and drop functionality but while dragging I am trying to retrieve index of that particular div which I want to drop

```
var data = new Array ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
var data1 = new Array ("c","b","e","d","a","f","g");
var check ="" ;
var test = "";
var test1 = 0;
var str = "abcdefg";            
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello");

$('.content').each(function(){

var text1 = $(this).text();
var element = this;
var draggab = new webkit_draggable($(this).attr('id'),{

onStart : function(){
var text1 = $(element).text()
console.log("start"+text1);},
var dropable = webkit_drop.add($(this).attr('id'),{
accept : ['content'],

onDrop:function(){
   var thise = $(this);
   console.log($(thise).index(this));
    console.log("Drop");
   alert($('.content').index() )
   alert(text1)
   alert(data[$('.content').index(this)] == text1);
   if(data[$('.content').index(this)] == text1)
   {                                                                  
var condrop=$(this).html()
                                                      alert(condrop);
                                            $(element).html(condrop);
                                            $(this).html(text1);

                                        }
  },
```

Here content is div id and I want index of that particular div.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```
onDrop:function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  console.log("Drop");
  console.log($this.index());
);
```

Comment: I try this but it will return -1